# Shared space incline equipment options (living room)

Tags: weightlifting, exercise-equipment, bench-press

I exercise in a shared family space, so no 'dedicated' exercise equipment would work.  When doing weight lifting with dumbells/powerblocks, often the exercises require some form of 'incline' for chest and shoulder exercises.  The challenge is, finding a shared-space friendly piece of equipment to support incline-based exercises.

I have a large exercise ball I've used to-date, but its time to move it out of this shared space.

Ask for help - any ideas/options of alternative incline options?  I've tried to find a heavy floor 'wedge' (kind of like a gymnastic wedge) that could double for the kids to sit on while watching TV without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This might be an unsatisfying answer, but the need for specialized equipment is one reason that I don't worry about incline exercises and instead focus on overhead presses and horizontal presses like push-ups or floor and bench press.

Answer (score 3):

In this pandemic-based home workout era, anything goes for me. Yesterday, I did incline dumbbell chest press while sitting in my office chair with it reclined. This was my more successful attempt. Previously, I was sitting on the floor against a couch with a small pillow behind my back.

So far, I've found that I like decline pushup more. I've got a lot more surfaces where I can just raise my feet. My dumbbells only go up to 24 lb as well so the pushups challenge me more. I'll do them weighted with a backpack if I end up getting good at them.